# Get the min value of a week in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So lets say I have a pandas dataframe with SOME repeated dates:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

reportDate = pd.date_range('04-01-2010', '09-03-2021',periods = 5000).date
lowPriceMin = [random.randint(10, 20) for x in range(5000)]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['reportDate'] = reportDate
df['lowPriceMin'] = lowPriceMin
```

Now I want to get the min value from every week since the starting date. So I will have around 559 (the number of weeks from '04-01-2010' to '09-03-2021') values with the min value from every week.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df['reportDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reportDate'])

>>> df.set_index("reportDate").resample("W").min()

            lowPriceMin
reportDate             
2010-01-10           10
2010-01-17           10
2010-01-24           14
2010-01-31           10
2010-02-07           14
                ...
2021-02-14           11
2021-02-21           11
2021-02-28           10
2021-03-07           10
2021-03-14           17

[584 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I had something similar but I thought that the value in `lowPriceMin` was the value in the `reportDate`